How to change the color of connectors in p-timeline in prime ng angular
How to change the color of the
connectors in p-timeline in prime ng angular.
In prime ng documentation they have just provided the template for content,markers and opposite.
I want to dynamically change the connector color through ts file.

welcome to the community pls explain more about your efforts what you have tried already so someone can understand your problem batter https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

The documentation mentions "p-timeline-event-connector: Connector element of an event." is that not what you're looking for?

In html file, <p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal"> {{event.month}} 

You can add like these
 <div class="p-timeline-event-connector [style.backgroundColor]="!event.reached ? event.color:   '#E0E0E0 '"></div>

My events were defined like these and I updated the reached based on condition.
this.events = [
      { status: 'Pending', date: '2023-10-01', icon: 'pi pi-shopping-cart', color: '#E0E0E0', description: 'Order placed' , reached : false},
      { status: 'Confirmed', date: '2023-10-02', icon: 'pi pi-check', color: '#E0E0E0', description: 'Order is being processed' , reached : false },
      { status: 'Shipped', date: '2023-10-03', icon: 'pi pi-truck', color: '#E0E0E0', description: 'Order shipped' , reached : false },
      { status: 'Delivered', date: '2023-10-04', icon: 'pi pi-check', color: '#E0E0E0', description: 'Order delivered' , reached : false },
      { status: 'Cancelled', date: '2023-10-05', icon: 'pi pi-times', color: '#E0E0E0', description: 'Order cancelled'  , reached : false},
    ];

